# How do I skip a profile and continue through the rest of the code in an iteration in python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

While I am iterating through a bunch of LinkedIn profiles I came across profile which is private (can be visible as 'LinkedIn Member') (which I cannot access). So, I am trying to skip that one profile in my loop and continue with the rest of the loop. However this is not happening.

Below is that piece of code I have used to skip that profile:

```
while i<page_length:
profiles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="entity-result__title-text  t-16"]/a[@class="app-aware-link"]')
profiles = [profile.get_attribute('href') for profile in profiles]
for profile in profiles:
    skip_profile =  sel.xpath('//*[@class="entity-result__title-text  t-16"]/a[@class="app-aware-link"]/text()').extract()
    if skip_profile == "'LinkedIn Member'":
        continue
    driver.get(profile)
    sleep(5)
    sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    name = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first().split(' | ')[0].strip()
```

The page I am trying to iterate is Amazon employee website with 10 profiles in each page.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me out on this.

Cheers!!

Comment: Are you sure skip_profile is 'LinkedIn Member' and not just LinkeIn Member?'

Comment: so like if you say print(skip_profile) on something you think you should be skipping, what do you see?

Comment: This is what I see when printing skip_profile:

Comment: ['\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', 'LinkedIn Member', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ', '\n        ', '\n      ']

Comment: Then you need to check if it contains 'LinkedIn Member' (i.e. when you try to find that substring, you don't get -1), not that it is "LinkedIn Member', because clearly it has other stuff along with that.

Comment: so if skip_profile.find("LinkedIn Member'")>-1:

Comment: Looking at it again, I see skip_profile is an array, so it won't match one string. You need see if sel_profile.contains("'LinkedIn Member'")